# String to long array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, type-conversion, long-integer

I understand that one can convert a string to a character array like so:

```
string a = "abcdefgh";
char b[8];
strcpy(b, a.c_str());
cout << (int)b[3];
```

Here I get the output `100`.

My questions is: How can I convert the string into an array of `long`. I am wondering how I can convert for example the string "abcdefgh" into an array `long b[2]`. The first long (`b[0]`) should be the long `0x61626364` and the second (`b[1]`) should be `0x65666768`. If that makes sense. So

```
cout << (unsigned int)b[0]
```

should output `1001633837924`.

Comment: The language includes operators that can operate on bits, including shift (`<<`, `>>`) and bitwise-or (`|`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "abcdefgh" );
    long b[2] = {};

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0, j = 0; i < 2 && j < s.size(); j++ )
    {
        b[i] = b[i] << 8 | ( unsigned char)s[j];
        if ( j % sizeof( long ) == sizeof( long ) - 1 ) i++;
    }

    std::cout << std::hex << b[0] << '\t' << b[1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
61626364    65666768
```

It would be even better to substitute statement

```
        if ( j % sizeof( long ) == sizeof( long ) - 1 ) i++;
```

for

```
        if ( j % sizeof( *b ) == sizeof( *b ) - 1 ) i++;
```

In this case you could change the type of b without changing all other code. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string s( "abcdefgh" );
    long long b[2] = {};

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 0, j = 0; i < 2 && j < s.size(); j++ )
    {
        b[i] = b[i] << 8 | ( unsigned char)s[j];
        if ( j % sizeof( *b ) == sizeof( *b ) - 1 ) i++;
    }

    std::cout << std::hex << b[0] << '\t' << b[1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
6162636465666768    0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reinterpret_cast` if your system uses the right **endianess**.

For example (it's not your expected output):

```
std::string a = "abcdefgh";
const long* b = reinterpret_cast<const long*>(a.data());
std::cout << std::hex << b[0] << " " << b[1] << std::endl;
// 64636261 68676665
```

If you want to get the other one, you'll have to code it yourself or use byte swap operations. Example with MSVC:

```
#include<Bits.h>
// ....
std::cout << std::hex << _byteswap_ulong(b[0]) << " " << b[1] << std::endl;
// 61626364 68676665
```

It's easy to build the result with `std::transform`:

```
std::string a = "abcdefgh";
const long* b = reinterpret_cast<const long*>(a.data());
long c[2];
std::transform(b, b+2, c, _byteswap_ulong);
std::cout << std::hex << c[0] << " " << c[1] << std::endl; 
// 61626364 65666768
```